# Correct Firebase database layout for a user to user (and group) chat app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to understand the best database structure to store and retrieve user to user conversations using the Firebase database for a chat app (web based).

My current plan is to give each chat its own ID which would be created by combining the unique Firebase IDs of the two chat participants (like `UserID1_UserID2`), for example: `FQ5d0jwLQDcQLryzevBxKrP72Bb2_GSIbxEMi4jOnWhrZaq528KJKDbm8` this chat ID would be stored in the database, and would contain the messages sent between the two participants.

Example layout:

```
MYAPP
    |_______conversations
    |                   |_____UserID1_UserID2
    |                   |                   |
    |                   |                   |__OshwYF72Jhd9bUw56W7d
    |                   |                   |                     |__name:"Jane"
    |                   |                   |                     |__text:"Hello!"
    |                   |                   |
    |                   |                   |__KbHy4293dYgVtT9pdoW
    |                   |                   |__PS8tgw53SnO892Jhweh
    |                   |                   |__Qufi83bdyg037D7RBif
    |                   |                   |__Gicuwy8r23ndoijdakr
    |                   |
    |                   |_____UserID5_UserID16
    |                   |_____UserID8_UserID7
    |                   |_____UserID3_UserID8
    |
    |_______users
```

Whenever a user signs into the app, they'll see a list of their contacts. When they select one to chat with, I would use some Javascript to combine their, and their selected friend's Firebase ID to generate the chat ID. This chat ID would then be either created in the database (if it's their first time to chat), or it would be used to load previous messages that they have exchanged (if they have chatted before), from the database.

My question is, is this the correct method to use? What issues might I run into if I use this method? For example, would I have problems if I try to implement group conversations (with more than 2 people) in the future?

I'd be really grateful for any help, or examples of the correct database layout logic for a person to person (and group) chat application using Firebase/a no SQL database.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See also our [sample apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/) which include fully functional chat.

Answer (score 0):

Something that I would like to point out as one of the most important "*rules*" to consider when creating a NoSQL database is that you must

> **Structure your data after the view.**

This means that the data must be structured in such a way, that when you want to display it on your view (probably your html pages) you do a single read.

So in order to find the best way to structure your database, you must first look at your view. And try to imagine how you would read data (direct reads and queries).

Altought your current structure looks good (for what you're building now), yes, you might have some problems when creating group chats. I would recommend using something like this:

[image]

You wil notice that this way, you can actually add more participants to each chat easily. Note that this isn't supposed to be your only node. You would have to create other nodes like users (to store the user details) and messages (store each chat's messages), etc
To help you with that, I recommend watching [David East's Firebase Database For SQL Developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: I thought of this method too... but based on one of the requirements how would you isolate a chat that has only user 1 and user 2 in it but not user 3? As an example. I'm logged in and click on user 2 and want to see the chat with just that user.